# Why does my java project runs so slow?

Tags: java

**EDITED**
I wrote a program to read in files and counts line, word, and character numbers. It takes command line arguments if there is any, otherwise ask user to type in the filenames. But when I try to run it, it takes forever; it builds successful though. I have no clue why it is doing this. Can anyone help? Thanks! Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class project2 {

static int lines = 0, words = 0, bytes = 0,
        totalLines = 0, totalWords = 0, totalBytes = 0;
static String[] filename;
static int i = 0;
static BufferedReader inFile = null;
//static File currentFile = new File(filename[i]);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length > 0) {  // if there are arguments on commandline
        for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
            filename[i] = args[j];
        }

    } else {  // prompt user to input file names
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput = input.readLine();  // read the user inputs as a string
        System.out.println("Please enter one or more file names, comma-separated: ");

        userInput = userInput.replaceAll(" ", ""); // delete all the whitespaces
        filename = userInput.split(",", -1);  // split the line into sub-strings by comma
    }

    System.out.println("This program determines the quantity of lines, "
            + "words, and bytes in a file or files that you specify.");
    System.out.println("%n");

    for (i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
        Count();
        totalLines = totalLines + lines;
        totalWords = totalWords + words;
        totalBytes = totalBytes + bytes;
    }

    System.out.format("%10s%10s%10%n", "Lines", "Words", "Bytes");
    System.out.format("%10s%10s%10%n", "--------", "--------", "--------");

    Print();
    for (i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
        inFile.close();
    }

    //return;
}

public static void Count() throws IOException {
    inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename[i]));
    String currentLine = inFile.readLine();
    while (currentLine != null) {
        lines++;
        String[] WORDS = currentLine.split(" "); // split the string into sub-string by whitespace
        // to separate each words and store them into an array
        words = words + WORDS.length;
        for (String word : WORDS) {
            bytes = bytes + word.length();
        }
        currentLine = inFile.readLine();

    }

}

public static void Print() {
    for (i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
        System.out.format("%10d%10d%10d%-15s%n", lines,
                words, bytes, filename[i]);
    }
    if (filename.length < 2) {  // if there's only one file, do not print out anything else

    } else {  
        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.format("%10d%10d%10d%-15s", totalLines, totalWords, totalBytes, "Totals");

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code and see what it does, you will probably be surprised...

Comment: `while (line != null)` is an infinite loop. And your logic is flawed anyway: you want to read the file three times? Why? Read it once and get word and character count for each read line.

Comment: @Tom why is it a infinite loop? I thought it reads till the end of the line?

Comment: @Ace_J Because the value of the `line` variable never changes inside the loop. Therefore, `line` will always be not `null`

Comment: @alfasin when I try to debug, it stuck right after the first for loop inside of the first if statement.

Comment: @Ace_J That is to be expected because there is more than one line in your input file. I suggest you lay it out with `lines++;` on a separate line and you will see it is incrementing for each line;. In fact I suggest you use your IDE to format all your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: BTW `wordCount()` will be reading from the end of the file since you don't re-open it and when you do this you will have an infinite loop as you only read one line.  Use the loop for the first method.

Comment: Once you have fixed all the bugs in your code you could think about how you can get the line, words and byte count reading the file just once in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this block:

```
for (i=0;i<filename.length;i++){

        totalLines = totalLines + lineCount();
        totalWords = totalWords + wordCount();
        totalBytes = totalBytes + byteCount();
}
```

Each of your `lineCount()`, `wordCount()`, and `byteCount()` methods are separately reading each of your files in the `filename` array, which means 1 file is being read line-by-line 3 times. This IO overhead is unneccessary. Try refactoring your code so that you read each *line* once, and calculate the wordCount and byteCount for that line all while the line is in memory.

Something like this:

```
while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null){
    lineCount++;
    wordCount += countWords(line);
    byteCount += countBytes(line);
}
```

You will, of course, have to implement the `countWords` and `countBytes` to operate on a single line.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Actually one file is being read once, the other methods just attempt to read from the end of the file.

Comment: Good catch. Surprised that wordCount and byteCount would return anything other than 0.

Comment: jakeblues @Peter Lawrey My professor doesn't want us to write everything in main, so I was trying to separate them into 3 methods. How can I read the file once but return 3 variables? or how do I reopen the file without too much overhead?

Comment: One of the problem with readLine() is you don't know whether the newline was one byte or two, if this were count characters it could be fine.

Comment: @Ace_J You can return an object with three fields, or as you are doing here, set static fields (not ideal but it works)

Comment: I thought it was attempting to read the same file 3 times, but looking at the second loop after the one you mention it appears to be attempting 6 times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I really appreciate all your help, but I'm still confused. If I just wanna use the static variables, I only need to have one method outside of main, right? Sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: @Ace_J Yes, you can have one method called from main which sets three static fields.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've fixed the loop, but it's still taking forever to run? Please see my updated code.

Comment: @Ace_J when a program takes a long time to run I run it in the debugger without break points and after a few seconds I pause the program to see where it is. If I can't work out why it us taking so long I add a break point and step through the code. Your program should be able to read over 50 MB per second. If it's a 1 GB file it could take a while